# Jmeter module controller fails to find selected controller when called from another project

Tags: jmeter

I'm struggling in building modularity concept with Jmeter.

here what I'm trying to achieve:

**Test project** referencing external project via include controller

[image]

**External project**

Switch controller is used to call only specific logic
[image]

Module controller referencing other simple controller
[image]

Regardless the module controller in the **external project** has valid reference, I'm getting error in the **Test Project** that the same module controller has no selected controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce it using latest [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities/):

[image]

So if your version is lower - try upgrading, it might be the case you're suffering from a bug which has been fixed already.

Also check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), normally it should contain if not the reason of the failure, but at least a clue

Going forward consider sharing your test plans in XML format so it would be more easy to reproduce, screenshots are very nice but not everyone is willing to reconstruct your scenario by looking at them

Comment: Hi Dmiri, 

add another module controller in the external project which referencing to another simple controller